# separate groups of images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal is to create a image-carousel with 7 images in a row. 
I'm reading data from a json-file. This all works fine.

What I do not get working is a loop that separates groups of 7 images in separate  as per example below. Any advice is greatly appreciated for this jQuery-beginner.

```
<div class='active item'>
Image-1
Image-2
Image-3
Image-4
Image-5
Image-6
Image-7
</div>
<div class='item'>
Image-8
Image-9
Image-10
```

I tried with two things:

insertBefore

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, element) {
  var myString = $('<div></div>');
  if (index % 7 == 0) {
    $("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore(".span2");
  }
  myString.append($('<div class="span2">')
    .append($("<a href=" + index + " class='thumbnail'>"))
      .append("<img src=http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/col/tn/" + element.imgf + " alt='Image' style='max-width:100%;'/>")));
  myString.appendTo('#show-carousel');
```

if /else

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, element){
                var myString = $('<div></div > ');
if (index % 7 == 0) {
   myString.append("<div class='item'>");
   myString.append($("<div class='row-fluid'>")
     .append($(' < div class="span2"> ')
       .append($("<a href="+index+" class='thumbnail'>")
         .append("<img src=http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/col/tn/"+element.imgf+" alt='Image' style='max-width: 100%;'/>"))));
} 
else {
   myString.append($('<div class="span2">')
     .append($("<a href="+index+" class='thumbnail'>")
       .append("<img src=http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/col/tn/"+element.imgf+" alt='Image' style='max-width: 100%;'/>")));
}
myString.appendTo('#show-carousel');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the functionality of executing a callback for a certain portion of an array into a helper function.

```
// function that executes a callback for a portion of an array
function forEachArrayGroup(arr, start, end, fn) {
  if (end > arr.length) end = arr.length; // normalize for out of bounds 
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    fn(arr[i], i);
  }
}
```

This would allow you to separate the logic of splitting data into portions from adding data to the DOM:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += 7) {

  // we create an item that will hold the portion
  const $item = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  // append the group to the current item
  forEachArrayPortion(items, i, i + 7, function(dataItem, index) {
    // this executes for each item in the group

    const $imgWrapper = // create the a, img and rest

    $item.append($imgWrapper);
  });
}
```

Here's a full example:

```js
const data = { items: Array.from({ length: 18 }, (_, i) => i).map(() => ({ imgf: 'i_am_fake' })) };

function forEachArrayGroup(arr, start, end, fn) {
  if (end > arr.length) end = arr.length; // normalize for out of bounds 
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    fn(arr[i], i);
  }
}

function displayItemsInGroups(items, groupSize) {

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += groupSize) {
    // this executes for each group of `partSize` number of items

    // we create an item that will hold the group
    const $groupItem = $('<div class="item"></div>');

    // make sure the first item is active
    if (i === 0) {
      $groupItem.addClass('active');
    }

    // create the row that will contain the image groups
    const $groupRow = $("<div class='row-fluid'>");

    // add group row to the current item
    $groupRow.appendTo($groupItem);

    // add current item to the carousel
    $groupItem.appendTo('#show-carousel');

    // append the group to the current row
    forEachArrayGroup(items, i, i + groupSize, function(dataItem, index) {
      // this executes for each item in the group

      const $imgWrapper = $('<div class="span2">')
        .append($("<a href=" + index + " class='thumbnail'>")
          // fake image
          .append("<div class="+dataItem.imgf+">Image "+(index+1)+"</div>"));

      $groupRow.append($imgWrapper);
    });
  }
}

displayItemsInGroups(data.items, 7);
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.item.active {
  border-color: #018bbc;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="show-carousel"></div>
```

Comment: The first div should have class active. I could easily get there with your solution by making a condition if the `i` is 0. Works great. I had to let go for the 'const' though. What is the specific reason for the use of this if I may aks?

Comment: Ok, let me add this to the answer as well. As far as `const`, it is an ECMAScript6 declaration type that means a `const` variable reference, once created, cannot be changed. I tend to use it for every variable that I know doesn't change, this way I know that if something isn't `const`, it's being changed somewhere -> for example, the `i` in the `for` loop is being incremented every loop iteration so I use `let` there instead.

Comment: just one more thing.. after the 'class=item' (this is before the 'class=span2') there is one more div needed (div class="row-fluid"). What is the magic to do this?

Comment: Does each entire group, i.e `.item`, need to be wrapped in `row-fluid` or does each image in the group, i.e. `.span2`, need to be wrapper in `row-fluid`?

Comment: just each `.item`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132238/discussion-between-user1037763-and-nem035).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to separate the images in groups of 7. To do this, you are on the correct path by using Modulus.

I would test to see when your loop index mod seven equals zero and then append a div group. Check out the code below.

```js
var $carousel = $('#show-carousel'),
  $item,
  myArr = [],
  i;

// populate our array with some fake data.
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var imgInfo = {
    imgf: 'image' + (i + 1) + '.jpg'
  };
  myArr.push(imgInfo);
}

//  loop through the array and add your items to your element
$.each(myArr, function(index, obj) {
  if (index % 7 === 0) {
    // create a div that will hold your images
    $item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    // append this div to our carousel element
    $carousel.append($item);
  }
  // $item is a reference to the last created div
  $item.append('<div class="span2"><a href="' + index + '" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/col/tn/' + obj.imgf + '" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>');
});

$('.item:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

```css
#show-carousel .item {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#show-carousel .item.active {
  display: block;
}
#show-carousel .item .span2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-carousel"></div>
```

*edit: updated code to better reflect what you had in your example.